# Добавление класса по условию. VUE

Tags: vue.js

Хочу реализовать тест, чтобы при правильно выбранном ответе добавлялся класс `green`. У меня же классы добавляются ко всем элементам, так как идёт реактивная перерисовка страницы, а `answer`уже `true`. Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы привязка была только к элементу со статусом правильного ответа после клика но нему.Заранее спасибо.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
   answer: undefined,
    questions: [
      { text: "Ответ №1", status: true },
      { text: "Ответ №2", status: false },
      { text: "Ответ №3", status: true },
    ]
  },
  methods: {
   check: function(status){
     return this.answer = status;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#app *{
  margin: 10px;
}

.green{
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>Вопросы:</h2>
  <ol>
    <li v-for="question in questions" @click="check(question.status)" :class="{green:answer}">
        {{question.text}}
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: :class="{green:question.status}"

Comment: Интересует именно после клика на элемент.